# React Input don't change when I set a initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating CRUD using ReactJS but I have a problem with the React Forms.

in some cases, I need to set an initial value in my input and I am using a logical operator for this, everything is ok, but when I change the value from the input, the value from the input doesn't change.

My component:

```js
export function Modal(props) {

  const [inputsValues, setInputsValues] = useState({
    id: '',
    nameInput: '',
    emailInput: '',
    phoneInput: ''
  })

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    inputsValues[event.target.name] = event.target.value
    setInputsValues()
  }
  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(inputsValues)
  }

  return (
    <div className={`area-modal ${props.isOpen ? 'open' : null}`}>
      <div className="modal">
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} action="">
          <label htmlFor="">Name</label>
          <div className="area-input">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="nameInput"
              value={inputsValues.nameInput}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </div>
          <label htmlFor="">Phone</label>
          <div className="area-input">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="phoneInput"
              value={props.dataForm ? props.dataForm.phone : ''}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </div>
          <label htmlFor="">Email</label>
          <div className="area-input">
            <input
              type="email"
              name="emailInput"
              value={props.dataForm ? props.dataForm.email : ''}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </div>
          <button>{props.buttonText}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
inputsValues[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
setInputsValues();
```

you need to use `setInputsValues` to update the state with the new value:

```
const { name, value} = e.target;
setInputsValues({ ...inputsValues, [name]: value });
```

Comment: There is only one way to setState in functional components usieng hook and that is using setInputValues() function and pass the new state to it. 
`inputValues[event.target.name] = event.target.value` does not working to setState. and when you call setInputValues() without any parameter nothing happen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the updated input data into your `setInputsValues`, for example:

```
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    inputsValues[event.target.name] = event.target.value
    setInputsValues({...inputsValues});
  }
```

When working with object-based states like this, it is usually good practice to use the [destructured assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to ensure the state updates.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `react`s [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), you don't need to set the state manually. It handles state for you. Also it's better to use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to change the state. So you can change `handleInputChange` same the bellow:

```
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputsValues({...inputsValues, [name] : value })
  }
```